# How do I determine if I am running 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: gui, versions, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os)

This question seems to come up quite regularly. The answer I know is to go to terminal and type `uname -m` if it says "x86_64" then I am running 64 bit. Can this be accomplished using GUI?