# How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?

Tags: architecture

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu from the official site.
However, I don't know if I installed the 32-bit or 64-bit version.

In Windows 7 I could right click *My Computer* and it listed which version it was.

**Is there an easy way to check in Ubuntu?**

Comment: Related: [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7034/62483)

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189640/how-to-find-architecture-of-my-pc-and-ubuntu

Comment: video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d39JLc5regY]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the OS architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) from a file on a disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/640163/how-can-i-determine-the-os-architecture-32-bit-or-64-bit-from-a-file-on-a-disk)

Comment: Installation architecture and kernel architecture are two different things. For example I implemented debian multiarch support via`dpkg --add-architecture amd64` and installed some `amd64` packages in my 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04. Now I run 32 bit installation with 64 bit kernel without problem. So while `dpkg --print-architecture` prints `i386`, `uname -m` prints `x86_64`. Refer to https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO (it's a tricky process)

Answer (score 717, accepted):

I know at least 2 ways. Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

1. `uname -a`

   Result for 32-bit Ubuntu:

   ```
   Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
   ```

   whereas the 64-bit Ubuntu will show:

   ```
   Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   ```

   Shorter version:

   ```
   $ uname -i
   x86_64
   ```

   or
2. `file /sbin/init`

   Result for 32-bit Ubuntu:

   ```
   /sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
   ```

   whereas for the 64-bit version it would look like:

   ```
   /sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
   ```

   Same for systems using systemd (16.04):

   `file /lib/systemd/systemd`

   Result for 64-bit:

   ```
   /lib/systemd/systemd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=54cc7ae53727d3ab67d7ff5d66620c0c589d62f9, stripped
   ```

Comment: Method 2, which consists of "sniffing" the (binary) content of a widely available executable, is quite indirect and awkward. While it works for most setups, the mere *presence* of a 64bit executable should not be a reliable way of detecting the *running* OS architecture. Specially when you consider `multiarch`, `ia32_libs` and, specially in your `init` example, `upstart`

Comment: You are probably right, but Method 1 displayed me a `i686` neither of 32 or 64 output was displayed for me

Comment: @aleks that is 32 bit (see the highlighted text: ` i686 i686 i386` in the answer)

Comment: it is 32 bit, I have used the second method, but the first did't show me anything that looked like `i386` :) but your answer helped. thanks a lot

Comment: `# file /sbin/init` -- `/sbin/init: symbolic link to `upstart'` -- `# file /sbin/upstart` -- `/sbin/upstart: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64...`

Comment: To method 1: You get the item highlighted with bold letters also by just running `uname -i` or `uname --hardware-platform`. No need for `uname -a` with lots of confusing stuff. The other i686 items are displayed by `uname -m`/`uname --machine` (first item) and `uname -p`/`uname --processor` (second item), but I don't know how their meaning differs from each other. On my machine, all of the three display "i686"...

Comment: Exactly, uname shows only one i686 on my 10.10 system, then i686 for all three fields after upgrading to 14.04 (I didn't check anywhere in between). Whereas, I think checking `/sbin/init` is guaranteed to work (at least while we still have it--I'm thinking that goes away with systemctl). If init is 32-bit, you have a 32-bit system.

Comment: @Auspex trough the years (from Unix on) it has been pretty weird to get this answered correctly. I agree init is the best but also that it will dissappear :D Lucky for us 32-bit is almost dead :-X

Comment: In my Ubuntu 16.04 /sbin/init is a symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd. `file /lib/systemd/systemd` worked fine.

Comment: what if I get armv7l from uname -i?  Is that 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: ARMv7 (and below) is 32-bit. ARMv8 introduces the 64-bit instruction set.

Comment: I don't know if you want to add this or not, but if you pass the `-L` flag to `file` to make `file` follow symbolic links automatically--that is, run `file -L /sbin/init`--then it will work on all versions of Ubuntu. It will work whether or not `/sbin/init` is a symlink (and whether it's upstart or systemd).

Comment: For `Raspebrry Pi Zero W Raspbian Stretch` method #1 returns: `uname -a` --> `Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59+ #1047 Sun Oct 29 11:47:10 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux` or `uname -i` --> `unknown`. Method #2 returns `file /lib/systemd/systemd` --> `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=8c1f19d39febf97f068d5e2726b345ad348030b6, stripped`

Answer (score 147):

### Ubuntu 12.04+ with Unity

- Hit Command(mac) or Window key.
- Type `Details`, and select "Details" icon
- Read "OS type" field
- 64 bit OS will read "64-bit"

[image]

**Alternative to get the above screen:**

- click System Menu (gear at top right corner)
- click "About this Computer"

I know the terminal responses are good but I guess this is the GUI answer.  :)

### Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity

- Hit Command(mac) or Window key.
- Type `System info`, and select System Info icon
- Read "OS type" field
- 64 bit OS will read "64-bit"

Comment: +1: The GUI way is preferred over terminal commands for a user that is used to Windows and specifically asked for an *easy* way.

Comment: Also, another (GUI) way to get to the same screen: `System Menu (top right corner, near the clock) -> System Settings -> Details`

Comment: With an easy way most definitely in mind: please, anyone running older Ubuntus, provide your GUI equivalent! Especially for Lucid Lynx (as the LTS is supported till 2015 and hence might well be running on people's hand-me-down laptops.)

Comment: @J-P: For older Ubuntus, such as Lucid Lynx, the easiest GUI way I know of is Gnome's **System Monitor**. Its `System` tab shows the architecture.

Comment: The GUI window is lovely, but imagine if you will for a minute if your running the server edition without the GUI installed?

Comment: The GUI way is usually very nice but it's also very likely that in 1 or 2 years it won't work like that anymore. On the other hand the CLI way will likely still work after many years. Unfortunately the CLI way has a barrier to entry though.

Comment: For 17.10 open "Settings" instead and choose Details  in the left column.

Answer (score 100):

A very easy and short way is:

Open the Terminal, write the following and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

The resulting number (in my case 64) is the answer.

[image: terminal - getconf LONG_BIT]

Comment: On my 32 bit system, this gives the correct answer as well.  Of all the command listed in various answers, the output of this one is the most straightforward.

Comment: Except:
    $ getconf LONGBIT
    getconf: Unrecognised variable `LONGBIT'

Comment: You're missing the underscore @Auspex LONG_BIT

Comment: @Michael Damn, so I was. I don't know how I managed that, and having upgraded those two machines to 64 bit in the past month, it's pretty much moot now ;-)  Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 63):

Reference: [How Do I Know if I’m Running 32-bit or 64-bit Linux?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24842/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-32-bit-or-64-bit-linux-answers/)

Use the command:

```
uname -m
```

You will typically get:

```
i686
```

for 32-bit (or possibly i586 or i386), and:

```
x86_64
```

for 64-bit.

Comment: hard to believe that /etc/release doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: `uname -mpi` gives all of the things mentioned in `uname -a`, even though they are usually all the same...

Answer (score 30):

Open terminal and try the `arch` command. If its output is x86_64 then it's 64 bit. If it says i686, i386, etc. then it's 32 bit.

However, the best way to determine the architecture is to run the `arch` command and google the output.

Comment: `arch` is just the same as `uname -m` (even stated in the manpage). ;-)

Comment: On my computer (Ubuntu 9.04), the arch command doesn't seem to exist. So I'd say uname -m is more reliable.

Comment: @JonathanSternberg: it was added a few months later, developed by the same authors of `uname` and included in the same `coreutils` package. So from Ubuntu 10.04 onwards both commands are available.

Answer (score 26):

`dpkg --print-architecture` command will display whether you have installed a 32 bit or 64 bit Ubuntu OS.

#### On 64 bit systems

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

#### On 32 bit systems

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
i386
```

`

Comment: The only method so far to correctly detect a 32bit OS running a 64bit kernel.

Answer (score 8):

Architecture Checker

[image]

[Download Link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5262820/download)

1. Download It
2. Extract it.
3. [Mark the file Architecture Checker.sh Executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui/35528#35528) and run it.

---

The script is basically this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ARCH=$(uname -m)
if [ "$ARCH" = "i686" ]; then
 zenity --info --title="Architecture Checker" --text="Your Architecture is 32-Bit"
fi
if [ "$ARCH" = "x86_64" ]; then
 zenity --info --title="Architecture Checker" --text="Your Architecture is 64-Bit"
fi
```

This will need to be in a executable text file, and `zenity` will need to be installed.

Comment: Honestly need to download and extract that 8 line file? Just put it in a code block here.

Comment: and when the output of `uname -m` is not `i686`... nice use of `zenity`, could use `notify-send` though.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the *System Settings* and under the *System* section, hit *Details*. You will get every detail including your OS, your processor as well as the fact whether the system is running a 64-bit or a 32-bit version.

Comment: That seems wonderful.
But I don't know how to "Go to the System Settings".
(BTW) I'm using 12.4 MATE.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for `lib32`.  If that turns up any results, you are on a 64-bit install (the results are compatibility libraries for running 32-bit applications on a 64-bit install).

Not exactly a better answer, but at least it doesn't require a terminal...  ;-)

**Edit**

I found an even easier one: open Help -> About Mozilla Firefox and you will see it right there...  ;-)

At the bottom it displays the "user agent string", e.g. on my 64-bit system:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; nl; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.12
```

or on my 32-bit system:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; nl; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.12
```

`x86_64` is 64-bit, `i686` is 32-bit

(But this is still not the answer that should be there ;) )

Comment: Pure GUI, sure, but quite a fragile one... packages whose names (*or descriptions*) contain `lib32` is surely *not* a reliable way of detecting architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The power button (top-most, extreme right) has an "About this Computer" option. :)

Comment: not on 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

You should take in mind that you may have a 64 bit CPU while you install a 32 bit kernel. I.e. If your CPU is 64 it doesn't mean that your OS is 64, it depends on what you've installed.

`man uname`

```
   -m, --machine
          print the machine hardware name

   -p, --processor
          print the processor type or "unknown"

   -i, --hardware-platform
          print the hardware platform or "unknown"
```

so to get the hardware platform use `uname -m` or `uname -p` or `uname -i` while to get the kernel type it's better to `getconf LONG_BIT` command.

Check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605813/getconf-returns-32-bit-on-x86-64-architecture)

Comment: Not actually relevant to the question: He _has_ a 64 bit CPU and wants to know which OS got installed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember, it is possible to install x86_64 kernel on a 32-bit system. As a few wrote here, you should look what libraries you have/what packages you have installed on your system. So the safest way to see is to check if you have `/lib64` and if it is a symlink to `/lib`.

Another possible way is to check what packages you have downloaded in `/var/cache/apt/archive`. If they contain _amd64.deb, it is a 64-bit system, that is, if you have installed packages and have not cleared your cache.

All of that can be done from [Konqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror)/[Dolphin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_%28file_manager%29) by just pointing and clicking or:

```
ls -la / |grep lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your Software Sources in Synaptic or Software Centre. If you haven't deleted your original source eg cdrom, it will (?) indicate the architecture. It's a GUI but it won't say '32bit' nor '64bit'.

Answer (score 0):

For debian derived systems.

On 64bits systems :

```
$ dpkg-architecture -q DEB_BUILD_ARCH
amd64
```

On 32bits systems :

```
$ dpkg-architecture -q DEB_BUILD_ARCH
i386
```

Answer (score 0):

To get reliable information about the OS, i.e. if the software installed and running on the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit, only two ways are recommended (using the command line). These are:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

and especially

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you call an OS being 32 bits.

To be specific, my kernel and desktop distribution is a 64 bits Debian/Sid, but I routinely use `schroot` to run a `deboostrap`-ed 32 bits Debian inside a `chroot`-ed environment (for testing purposes).

Do you feel that my 32 bits environment should be called 32 bits (I believe so) or 64 bits (after all, it does run inside a 64 bits kernel). In that environment `uname -m` says `i686` and all libraries and executables and processes are 32 bits.

For practical purposes `uname -m` should be enough. The `file` command can tell you if an ELF executable is a 32 bits or a 64 bits one.

See the Linux specific [personality(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/personality) syscall (and also the [uname(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname) one).

And the hardware information about your processor is visible with e.g.

```
 cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

its output is the same in my desktop 64 bits system and in my 32 bits schroot-ed environment.

Comment: -1: you added a *lot* of unnecessary confusion without adding *any* useful new info. Why saying that you're "not sure what you call an OS being 32 bits"? That's a pretty straightforward question, one you *know* about. Your `chroot` example is pointless: it is similar to a Virtual Machine, so of course `uname -m` will output `i686` if you bootstrapped it with a 32-bit OS. But the "host" is still 64 bits, and `uname -m` will say so if you run it outside the chroot environment

Comment: Also, `/proc/cpuinfo` is misleading: it shows the CPU *capabilities*, and *not* the actual installed (and running) OS architecture. Virtually all desktop CPUs sold in the last 5 years are 64-bit, but this has absolutely *nothing*  to do with the question. And of course it reports the same in both scenarios, since your CPU *hardware* is the same, and it is capable of running both 32 and 64 bits OSes.

Comment: @MestreLion, What Basile is trying to say is that in some cases, for example when using LXC or `chroot`, you may run a purely 32bit system with a 64bit kernel. In these cases `uname` will tell you the kernel architecture, 64bit, while other methods will tell you the userland architecture, 32bit, and it's not clear which of the two is "the" architecture.

Comment: @Joni: Ok, I understand. But that's an extremely corner-case scenario, and surely not the OP's case.

Comment: Probably it's not the OP's case, I just wanted to clarify the point Basile was trying to make (Also, it looks like my earlier edit to correct the answer was rejected? In this environment `uname -m` will output the kernel's architecture which is x86_64, not i686.)