# How to find architecture of my PC and Ubuntu?

Tags: versions, architecture

When running `uname -a`, I get as output

```
41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 13 17:59:54 UTC 2012 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone please explain to  me *why both i386 & i686* ?

What exactly is my PC architecture and what version of Ubuntu am I using (32bit or 64bit)?

Comment: is this a complete output from uname -a? I assume some fields like the kernel-name, kernel-version etc are missing.

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/q/41332/178596

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you using

Answer (score 129):

The command is `uname -m`.

Open a terminal try using `uname -m` command. This should show you the OS architecture.

If it gives any output like `ix86`, where x is 3,4,5 or 6, Your OS is 32bit.

You can also see the Ubuntu architecture by Opening "System monitor" and going in the **System** tab.

[image]

**Difference between hardware platform and Processor type**:

There is a difference between the hardware platform (which is given by `-i` switch) to the CPU type (given by `-p` switch).

The hardware platform tells us which architecture the kernel is built for (may be optimized though for later versions). It can be a i386.

However the Processor type refers to the actual processor type of your machine such as i686 (P4 and later builds).

Thanks to Schotty of this [this page](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/forums/showthread.php/9207-hardware-name-platform-CPU-type/page2). Here is [an answer from Unix stackexchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47020/difference-between-machine-hardware-processor-type-and-hardware-platform) on the same topic, though I didn't find the language enough clear (completely my fault).

Comment: On uname -m ,  
it says i686,what does this mean?
and my system monitor window says 
"Release 11.10(oneiric)
Kernel Linux 3.0.0-26-generic
GNOME 3.2.1"
It doesn't specifies any thing,like one shown in your pic.

Comment: i686 means 32bit

Comment: @Ubunu_beginner, i386 and i686 are both part of the x86 family of processors. They just refer to the specific age of the processor platform. i386 is an older platform (early 90s?) used back when 386 processors were used in machines. Then this was upgraded to 486 processors, which was the same basic instruction set as 386 just faster and newer. 586 was another upgraded and was when the term Pentium started floating around. Eventually all of these got encapsulated into the x86 architecture name. i686 just refers to the 6th generation of x86 architecture.

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 there is no system tab in system monitor

Comment: @coding_ninza You can find it in Settings -> About section. Have you found it?

Comment: yes I find it in setting after opening setting  I click on details and then it shows OS type-64-bit.

Comment: @Anwar Where'd you get your cool-looking System Monitor?  I have Ubuntu 16.04 but nothing fancy like that

Comment: @frank Thank you. Actually it was the gnome-system-monitor before gnome migrated to version 3. And I forgot the theme name. But You can use same system monitor by installing mate-system-monitor application

Comment: @Anwar I ask because mine literally doesn't have the "System" tab

Comment: Yeah I know. They've changed it a lot. @frank

Answer (score 25):

Use Anwar's answer to find the architecture.

Now here is the explanation for your second part of the question.

Below is the `uname` output: In my case I have installed a 32 bit version. Both i386 and i686 refer 32 bit version. `uname` will return x86_64 in case if it is a 64 bit version.

```
$ uname -a
Linux devav2 3.2.0-30-generic-pae #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 17:14:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

- **Linux(-s)** - OS/Kernel name
- **devav2(-n)** - hostname
- **3.2.0-30-generic-pae (-r)** - kernel release
- **48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 17:14:09 UTC 2012 (-v)** - Kernel version with time and SMP stands for symmetric multiprocessing, which means you have multiprocessor support
- **i686(-m)** - Machine hardware name
- **i686(-p)** - processor type
- **i386(-i)** - hardware platform
- **GNU/LINUX(-o)** - Operating System name

Below is grabbed from `uname --help` page which might help you to understand more about it.

```
 -a, --all                print all information, in the following order,
                             except omit -p and -i if unknown:
  -s, --kernel-name        print the kernel name
  -n, --nodename           print the network node hostname
  -r, --kernel-release     print the kernel release
  -v, --kernel-version     print the kernel version
  -m, --machine            print the machine hardware name
  -p, --processor          print the processor type or "unknown"
  -i, --hardware-platform  print the hardware platform or "unknown"
  -o, --operating-system   print the operating system
```

Comment: `uname -m` will return `x86_64` in case if it is a 64 bit version - This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

For debian Linux derived systems, one possible command is `dpkg-architecture -q DEB_BUILD_ARCH`.

On 64bits systems, it returns :

```
$ dpkg-architecture -q DEB_BUILD_ARCH
amd64
```

On 32bits systems, it returns :

```
$ dpkg-architecture -q DEB_BUILD_ARCH
i386
```

Comment: To avoid having to install `dpkg-dev`, you can just run `dpkg --print-architecture` instead.

Comment: @CallumRogers Can you please convert this comment to an answer ?

Answer (score 3):

I find @Callum Rogers 's comment to be the best answer:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

> amd64

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is the architecture you could always try the command called arch.  It is very terse.  It is not [POSIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/how-to-determine-linux-kernel-architecture).

Answer (score -2):

use **syscap** from Formake project https://sourceforge.net/projects/formake 
**syscap** allows to probe many system properties and test dependencies. It is a portable shell script.

Comment: Seems waaaaay overkill to get system architecture. According to your link "Formake is a toolkit for developing portable software build systems" (though I don't doubt it has a utility to check architecture) and is in alpha, so seems like nobody would want to install it for this simple purpose. If you're affiliated with the project, you should disclose that.