# When installing CUDA, how to determine distro,version and architecture parameters?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, cuda

The [installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation) says to run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

But how should I fill `distro`, `version` and `architecture`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use [the CUDA downloads website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal) and selected the appropriate options (say Linux, x86-64, Ubuntu, 16.04 in order), it will show the exact command you're supposed to run:

[image]

- The distro is Ubuntu (16.04 or 14.04 depending on what you're using, run `lsb_release -cd` to find out).
- The version is based on the CUDA release you're downloading.
- For the architecture, see [How to find architecture of my PC and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/189640/158442) - use `uname -m`.

Comment: Could you give an example ? What should I write as `distro` for Ubuntu 16.04 ? And what are the CUDA versions available and how to format them to `version` ?

Comment: @arthur.sw the site gives you an example. In the screenshot I selected Ubuntu and 16.04, and the resulting instructions had `ubuntu1604` in it. The downloads page is best for all of this - https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal

Comment: yes, maybe what puzzled me is that the instructions appear only once you selected all your choice ; I probably didn't select everything and didn't see the corresponding commands (or - less likely - the site changed since I tried last)

Answer (score 2):

The CUDA downloads site only reflects the latest version of CUDA. You should check the following as well:

1. Recommended [driver for your hardware](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx). For me on Ubuntu 20.04, my RTX 3090 graphics card should use driver version 470. See the [release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html), table 3 for the maximum corresponding CUDA version. In my case it's CUDA 11.4.x.
2. The GCC required by your CUDA version. On Ubuntu 20.04, the default GCC is `9.x`, so my maximum CUDA version is `11.4.0` (i did not want to install a newer GCC).
3. If you're using other packages that depend on a specific version of CUDA, check those as well (e.g the current latest Pytorch is compiled with CUDA 11.3).
4. Note the driver version for your chosen CUDA: for `11.3.1`, the driver version is `465.19.01`.

[The downloads site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) tells me to use `cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local_11.6.0-510.39.01-1_amd64.deb`. I will change the versions accordingly:

```
Distro:       ubuntu2004-11-6-local -> ubuntu2004-11-3-local
Version:      11.6.0-510.39.01-1    -> 11.3.1-465.19.01-1 (<CUDA version>-<driver version>)
Architecture: amd64 (no change)
```

So i change the downloads site output from:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.6.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local_11.6.0-510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local_11.6.0-510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local/7fa2af80.pub
```

to

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.3.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local_11.3.1-465.19.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local_11.3.1-465.19.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local/7fa2af80.pub
```

If you've installed the wrong version (e.g. 11.6) and want to undo, you can use

```
sudo apt remove cuda
sudo dpkg remove cuda
sudo apt-key remove /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-ubuntu2004-11-6-local.list
sudo rm -r /usr/local/cuda-11.6 
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/cuda /etc/alternatives/cuda-11
```