# Unable to locate package libc6-dev-i386

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 17.04, 32-bit, multiarch

I'm trying to install NS3, and got stuck at this package, libc6-dev-i386, installation.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 g++-multilib
```

I've tried all the possible solution that i can find on the google, so far.

Some details:

```
sudo dpkg --print-architectures   
i386
```

I've tried direct command,

1. `sudo apt install libc6-dev-i386`
2. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, and then try to run the update command.

   But again no luck, and i think this attempt is stupid coz my base architecture is i386, so i don't need to add it(can anybody confirm), but i tried it any way.
3. `sudo apt install -f`, even though i don't know what `-f` stands for.
4. I've also read that this package automatically installed with g++, and I've g++ 6.3.0.

I get the same error after all of those tries:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package libc6-dev-i386
```

I'm not getting, locate where, in the website?

**EDIT**

The o/p of, lsb_release -a.,

```
No LSB modules are available.      
Distributor ID: Ubuntu     
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04     
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

uname -a --

```
Linux tafri-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC 4.10.0-32-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 12:09:08 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

and yes i'm following instruction from.,
https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation

and, that "s" at the end of "architecture", is my bad. I was trying the foreign command.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit OS you don't need `libc6-dev-i386`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*On 32-bit Ubuntu, skip that package. Just install `libc6-dev` and whatever other packages you need.*

The specific package that corresponds to `libc6-dev-i386` for a 32-bit system is just `libc6-dev`, which you are already installing.

There is no `libc6-dev-i386` package for your system, because it's only available on 64-bit systems. This, in turn, is because its purpose is to provide you with the ability to build and run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit system.

---

Ubuntu [supports several architectures](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch02s01.html). For [PCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_computer), meaning most desktops and laptops, including those [manufactured by Apple in recent years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple%27s_transition_to_Intel_processors), there are two: i386 for 32-bit systems and amd64 for 64-bit systems. For the rest of this answer when I say "32-bit" and "64-bit" I am referring to those architectures specifically. (These [confusingly named](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus) architectures [have important differences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64), hardware [may support both or just i386](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose) though [you may need the amd64 version on UEFI systems](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/22949), and you can [check the architecture of your machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189640/how-to-find-architecture-of-my-pc-and-ubuntu) or [Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os).)

64-bit processors are capable of running both 64-bit and 32-bit native (machine language) code.

- If you have the 64-bit (amd64) version of Ubuntu, you can automatically run 64-bit programs.
- You can also run 32-bit programs, but you may need to install 32-bit support libraries, including the 32-bit version of `libc6`.

To run, most programs require the libraries provided by the `libc6` package. Ubuntu has this package installed already. Like most (but not all) packages in Ubuntu, the `libc6` package is provided separately for different architectures.

To *create* an executable that links to the libraries provided by `libc6`, you need to have the [header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) for that library. Those are provided by the `libc6-dev` package. The `libc6-dev` package also declares the `libc6` package as a dependency, because it would not usually be useful to have just the header files but not the library itself. Most `-dev` packages declare some corresponding non-`-dev` package as a dependency.

Because the vast majority of programs require `libc6` directly or indirectly, more than one way to install the 32-bit version of this library and its header files on a 64-bit system has been provided over the years.

- The most general way, which works with almost every other library as well, is to use [APT's multiarch support](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch)--[multiarch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) is enabled by default on all recent Debian and Ubuntu systems--by [running `dpkg --add-architecture i386`](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Configuring_architectures) and [using `apt` or `apt-get` to install](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Installing.2Fremoving_packages) the `libc6:i386` and `libc6-dev:i386` packages. `apt` and `apt-get` support specifying the architecture of a package to install using this `:` syntax.
- However, there are other ways. The 32-bit (`i386`) versions of some commonly needed libraries are provided as special `amd64`-only packages. [`libc6-i386`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6-i386&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [`libc6-dev-i386`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6-dev-i386&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) are two such packages. The `libc6-dev-i386` package [provides the 32-bit versions of header files that differ between architectures](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/libc6-dev-i386/filelist) while [declaring as dependencies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libc6-dev-i386) `libc6-dev`, which is sufficient for the others, and `libc6-i386`, which provides the actual 32-bit libraries.
- The *old* way to install common 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system was with [the `ia32-libs` package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package).

Based on the commands you ran, it seems like you tried *both* of the first two methods, or a combination of the two. However, your system neither requires nor is capable of either, since it's a 32-bit system. 32-bit systems don't need anything special to be able to run 32-bit programs (and they cannot run 64-bit programs).

Answer (score 5):

The development library `libc6-dev-i386` is only necessary for developing 32-bit software in a 64-bit OS.

According to the results posted (pending confirmation) the OS is 32-bit (i386) therefore it doesn't require the said library and the library isn't available in the repositories (it is available for 64-bit Ubuntu only).

The installation can proceed without it.

Comment: Okay, so how can i check the respective library for 32-bit system, to make sure.

Comment: The point is the library isn't required.

Comment: @tafri The respective library on a 32-bit system is just `libc6-dev` (which you're already installing). In case you're interested I've [posted a more detailed explanation](https://askubuntu.com/a/948374/22949).