# Need Help Trying out ubuntu amd64 on Windows 10 PC

Tags: 16.04, boot, usb, windows-10

I made the usb image restarted windows loaded.
I restarted hit F12 choose Load USB drive.
Then it restarted but it wouldn't pass the Bios check
it kept flashing and wouldn't stop. so, I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to restart.
this time it passed the bios check, but then a message said

> the iOS file (ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64) on The USB drive can't be read by windows. aborting operation, please remove USB drive.

I did, then the PC restarted
It took 30 minutes to restart after it started it said it has to repair windows OS files that were damaged. that took another 30 minutes.

I reread the documents of how to just try ubuntu. I did everything like it said but it will not let me try it out. So, I deleted the USB stick with CCleaner then rewrote the USB with the iOS file (ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64), and it did the same as the first time.

All I want to do is try it out, to see if its for me, or not.
This makes me wonder if the OS is going to do the same?

I am currently using Windows 10, 64-Bit.

Comment: Never mind. I have talked to people who has used this, and they say its a total pain in the rump. Plus you can't play most PC games, and you basically have to be a computer tech to use this Operating System.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I can say that Ubuntu is far easier now than it was five years ago in my experience, and better than Windows 10 / Surface Pro 4. If you want to play video games, though, perhaps Windows is better.

Comment: I do play a lot of Games. Can games for PC be played on this? I have tried 5 times to install this, but can't figure it out either i am doing something wrong, or windows 10 is blocking me from installing it? I have been told Windows 10 Will block anything it thinks may be a threat to it.

Comment: Regarding playing games designed for Windows on Linux, see [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) and the [apps people have gotten working](https://appdb.winehq.org/). Regarding installation, you should simply put the installation files on a CD or USB drive and boot the computer from it so the operating system you have installed shouldn't matter. However, if you already have Windows 10, it may be better to 'dual-boot', i.e. install Linux 'next to' Windows on your computer, and use both, and use Windows for playing games.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to verify that you are using the correct [architecture for your computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189640/how-to-find-architecture-of-my-pc-and-ubuntu): You may have downloaded the wrong installation file.

Linux is powerful insofar as you have control over your PC, but it's also a "double-edged sword" in that this can be a hassle as we lack Microsoft/Apple doing things for us ...