# How to choose a JDK for a given Ubuntu VM

Tags: virtualbox, java, jdk, architecture

My Windows 10 machine is an HP EliteBook 840 G6 running i5-8365U.  I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS as a VM on VirtualBox 6.1.28.  The ISO file ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso was from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

I have to choose a JDK 8 (LTS) from AdoptOpenJDK, HotSpot JVM, update 265.  This is on the second page of https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot.  The associated files can be found by search this age for string "265".

There are many Linux options to choose from:

```
  Linux ppc64le
  Linux s390x
  Linux x64
  Linux arm32
  Linux aarch64
```

I'm guessing that I choose "x64" because my Ubuntu ISO file name contains "amd64"?

I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu question or a VM question.

Comment: If you are using the 64-bit ISO (supported by Intel/AMD processors), then you'll want `x64` 

Comment: @matigo:  Thanks.  I will proceed.  Did you want to post that as the answer?

Comment: No need. It's a one-liner.

Comment: I meant to tie up a loose end so that "the system" isn't treating this question as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unsure of your system architecture, you can use the `uname -m` or `arch` command from a terminal. If you get x86_64 -> It's a x64.
You can refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189640/how-to-find-architecture-of-my-pc-and-ubuntu) for more details.

On a side note, as you have probably noticed, [AdoptOpenJDK has transitioned to Eclipse](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2021/03/transition-to-eclipse-an-update/) and https://adoptopenjdk.net won't be updated as of July 2021. The new website is https://adoptium.net, and the distribution name is now "Temurin". That said, if you specifically need a 265 build, Adoptium does not provide it and you better stick with AdoptOpenJDK.

Comment: Thanks, FloT.  You answered 2 questions, both helpful.  First, how to query the system for the architecture.  Second, how the returned label maps to the options listed in my posted question.  I appreciate the news about the change in AdoptOpenJDK.  However, I do in fact need update 265, build 01.  I am trying to ensure that results are the same as from last year, where I did some things on Windows using that update and build.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a X-Y problem, namely that all you *really* want is a JVM for your system.

> **tl;dr** `sudo apt install default-jdk`

As suggested by running `java` on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS WSL instance:

```
tra@Thunder:~$ java

Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72
sudo apt install openjdk-16-jre-headless  # version 16.0.1+9-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.7+5-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17+35-1~20.04
```

In other words, you have several already available in the Ubuntu package system.  Note that if you actually need to compile programs, you need more like the `javac` Java compiler.

```
tra@Thunder:~$ javac

Command 'javac' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless  # version 11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04, or
sudo apt install default-jdk              # version 2:1.11-72
sudo apt install openjdk-16-jdk-headless  # version 16.0.1+9-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless   # version 8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jdk-headless  # version 13.0.7+5-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk-headless  # version 17+35-1~20.04
sudo apt install ecj                      # version 3.16.0-1
```

Unnless you have very specific requirements there are very good odds that the `default-jdk` will do what you need.

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

(answer Yes, and watch the downloads pass by)

Then

```
tra@Thunder:~$ javac --version
javac 11.0.11
tra@Thunder:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Thanks, Thorbjorn Ravn Andersen.  I do in fact want update #265, Build 01.  I want to ensure as much similarity in the results of my usage as possible compared to work done using that same update and build on Windows last year.  But your more direct `sudo apt install default-jdk` should be very much preferred for more usual situations.

Comment: You may also want to compare with the Java 8 installed with `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

As per *matigo*'s comment, "If you are using the 64-bit ISO (supported by Intel/AMD processors), then you'll want x64."

I didn't actually have to download from the *adoptopenjdk* site https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot and try to figure out the installation.  Instead, I found Bash instructions at https://gist.github.com/phillipsj/950235f411dec9e0e90e199c6dde12e9 to "wget" the tarball and install it:

```
# install-openjdk-8.sh
#---------------------
wget -q https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-releases/releases/download/jdk8u172-b11/OpenJDK8_x64_Linux_jdk8u172-b11.tar.gz
tar -xf OpenJDK8_x64_Linux_jdk8u172-b11.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm && sudo mv jdk8u172-b11 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u172-b11
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u172-b11
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u172-b11/bin
java -version
```

I modified it for the URL of the tarball for my version, as found on the *adoptopenjdk* site, and fixed some pathologies that I experienced:

```
cd ~/tmp
wget -q https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u265-b01/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u265b01.tar.gz
tar -xf OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u265b01.tar.gz

# Did next steps manually in case version string
# in the file name had a different pattern.
# They didn't, so just replace jdk8u172-b11 with jdk8u265-b01.
# Can't just paste the lines en masse to the Bash prompt cuz
# "sudo" wants password from keyboard, so separate the compound line.
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
sudo mv jdk8u265-b01 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u265-b01

# The following exports probably need to go into ~/.profile or
# some-such.  I need to know which ~/.* file to put it in and/or
# why ~/.profile isn't run after a "su - user-name".  For now,
# manually source ~/.profile after "su".
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u265-b01
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u265-b01/bin"
java -version

   openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_265-b01)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)

which java javac

   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u265-b01/bin/java
   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u265-b01/bin/javac
```