# do I have ubuntu 64-bit?

Tags: architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine if I am running 32 bit or 64 bit OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os)

I installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo x61 laptop.
I assumed that would be a 32-bit version of the software.
How can I tell if it is 32- or 64-bit?

Thanks,

Larry Mehl

Answer (score 0):

On the top right of the screen , click on the little gear icon. (next to where the time and your username is displayed)
From the menu that pops up click on system settings.
Then on the system settings page , right at the bottom click on "Details".

That will show you some details as well as under "OS type" whether it is 32bit or 64bit.

Alternatively you can open a terminal and enter the command:

```
uname -a
```

This will also show if you are running i386 or 64bit kernel