# How can you install Oracle Java JDK 7 without an internet connection with noob friendly instructions?

Tags: installation, java, oracle

Is there any way that you can easily and I mean easily install Oracle Java JDK 7 in ubuntu with absolutely no internet connection. I'm asking because I am completely new to things(noob and newb) like this in Ubuntu. I have access to a Windows OS based computer that has internet but not at home which is the computer that has Ubuntu installed so I can download the needed files/materials to install and later bring them to my computer at home to install. I would like it if somewhere there were instructions that give every detail(even such as what application to open exactly what directory and how to access the directory etc...) to what must be done to get Oracle Java JDK 7 installed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than the initial download everything in the first answer will work offline.

Comment: Like I stated before I do not know what to do. I looked at the link in the first answer and I still am confused what to do since there are like 100 links(exaggerated) to a download and still confused with the installation instructions I looked at.

Comment: Unfortunately that's as simple as the instructions can get, Oracle doesn't make it easy for people to use their Java in linux.

Comment: You can select the right download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html - `jdk-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz` for a 32 bit system and `jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz` for a 64 bit. You can find the bit thing for your OS [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/41334/178596).