# Replace openjdk with oracle-jdk on Ubuntu

Tags: java, dependencies, openjdk

I have an ubuntu system and I want to replace my openjdk with oracle-jdk.

However if I remove my open-jdk and then install oracle-jdk, when I try to install some packages they want to install openjdk and I don't want this.

Is there any way to install those packages on top of oracle-jdk? One of those packages is freemind.

Comment: Which packages require open-jdk that you want to install? (besides freemind)

Comment: I caught oracle-jdk adding itself to `PATH` in `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`. Removing this file and starting a fresh shell allowed `update-alternatives` to do its job.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can completely remove the `OpenJDK` and fresh Install `Oracle Java JDK` by following these steps:

1. Remove `OpenJDK` completely by this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
   ```
2. Download the `Oracle Java JDK` [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

   **Note:** download appropriate file, for example if your system is x64 Ubuntu (i.e, Debian) the download file is named like this: `jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz`

   **To find which version is your OS, [check here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os)**
3. Create a folder named `java` in `/usr/local/`by this command:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
   ```
4. Copy the Downloaded file in the  directory `/usr/local/java`. To do this, `cd` into directory where downloaded file is located and use this command for copying that file to `/usr/local/java/`:

   ```
   sudo cp -r jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java/
   ```
5. CD into `/usr/local/java/` directory and extract that copied file by using this command:

   ```
   sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```
6. After extraction you must see a folder named `jdk1.8.0_51`.
7. Update `PATH` file by opening  `/etc/profile` file by the command `sudo nano /etc/profile` and paste the following at the end of the file:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51
   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   export JAVA_HOME
   export PATH
   ```
8. Save and exit.
9. Tell the system that the new Oracle Java version is available by the following commands:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javac" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javaws" 1
   ```
10. Make Oracle Java JDK as default by this following commands:

    ```
    sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java
    sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javac
    sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javaws
    ```
11. Reload sytem wide PATH /etc/profile by this command:

    ```
    source /etc/profile
    ```
12. Reboot your system.
13. Check Java JDK version by `java -version` command . If installation is succesful, it will display like the following:

    ```
    java version "1.8.0_51"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-xxx)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.51-xxx, mixed mode)
    ```

That's it!

**Note:** We Assumed that the downloaded file is named `jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz` and used this name in all the commands used in steps 2, 4 and 5. It may depends on the type of O.S, processor type (i.e., 32bit or 64bit)

Comment: Beside this is the correct way to manually install oracle-jdk there is a package available from WebUpd8 PPA which will be updated, too. So there is no need to install every new version manually. See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466166/your-java-version-is-out-of-date-on-ubuntu-2014-04/466172#466172

Comment: Instead of using the directory jdk1.8.0_51, create a symlink named just "jdk" to this directory and next time you update just extract the JDK tarball and recreate the symlink and you're done.

Comment: for ubuntu users: theres a foolproof method below from @mihaic that works well for me

Comment: You are rockstar

Comment: Please note that if you want to download the JDK in Ubuntu Server (without GUI), you can use the following command: `wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.4+11/c2514751926b4512b076cc82f959763f/jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz"`

You can always copied the latest version by go back the Oracle download page and generate a new one.

Comment: In some circumstances, you may need to search for `\*openjdk-\*` when finding packages to uninstall. When I used `openjdk-\*` to uninstall Java, only some packages were removed and `java -version` was still showing that a version of openjdk was on my system.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need to remove openjdk in order to use / install the oracle's jdk. Just install the oracle's jdk and configure which java you want to use by configuring it with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You can find more help here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: I need a way to have only one java on my ubuntu. tnx.

Comment: This is a great answer. Groovy on Debian jessie forces openjdk to be installed, but the work I do requires (don't ask) the Oracle JDK for compilation. This option allowed me to leave both openjdk and oracle jdk installed so everything plays nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04/16.04. In three steps:

1. Install the `oracle-java7-installer` (or `oracle-java8-installer`) from the webupd8team repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   ```
2. Make sure it works with the following command:

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   It should display something similar to:

   ```
   java version "1.7.0_76"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
   ```
3. (Optional) Remove the open-jdk if you really want/need to:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
   ```

You can find more information [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)

Comment: Followed your directions and got a
`Unable to find java executable. Check JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.`
error

Comment: surprised of finding my own answer one year later, this still works for *Ubuntu 16.04* and `oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: Got this when adding the repo:
`W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.`

Answer (score 8):

After removing openjdk, try this approach that worked for me:

Install oracle jdk 7 on ubuntu server (tested with ubuntu 12.0.4)

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

some more info here: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java

(note to adapt this for your version of jdk)