# "Your Java version is out of date." on Ubuntu 2014.04

Tags: updates, java, security

With fully updated Ubuntu 2014.04, Firefox tells me:

> Your Java version is out of date.

How to update Java?

Typing `java -version` in a terminal tells me:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Typing `which java` tells me `/usr/bin/java`.

Comment: Refer the URL http://askubuntu.com/questions/183867/how-do-i-update-oracle-java-7-jdk-and-jre for updating Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest Java 7 is **Version 7 Update 55** (date of writing). There are several important security updates that should be installed. To get the Oracle JDK and be provided with updates, too, use Webupd8 (pronounced webupdate) which provide a PPA to deploy Java.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

**UPDATE:** 
In order to install Java 8 just type

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: "Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer". Before running the `add-apt-repository` command you should run `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*` as well as `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`