# Installing Java Offline

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

I understand that this question has been asked exhaustively and do not mind if it is marked as a duplicate, but I am having a little trouble setting Java up. When I follow this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430434/replace-openjdk-with-oracle-jdk-on-ubuntu), number six says  that

> After extraction you must see a folder named jdk1.8.0_51

However with the new [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (at time of writing 8u66), when I extract the file, I just have one binary file. How do I set it up?

Comment: Why are you simply not using "apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk"?

Comment: @MaxKulik My internet is down at my place, and will only be back on Friday.

Comment: There is a project that I'd like to finish up as well.

Comment: what is the binary file you have? I just downloaded 1.8.0_65 tar.gz and it extracted the directory like your instructions. I seem to remember that some of them where installers along the way. So in that case you would have to set the file executable and run it.

Comment: @EddieDunn I download the 64bit JDK and I only find a tar file that has the same name as the archive I just extracted. If I execute it (like so: `./jdk-8u66....` etc I get a bash error. Did you download the 32bit JDK?

Comment: You still need to extract the tar. You can do it in one command with tar -xzf from the tar.gz

Comment: @EddieDunn Silly me, I thought tar wasn't working. I extract it on Windows and the rest will be history. Thanks Eddie.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Installing Java Offline**

Find out whether you are running a 32 bit or a 64 bit OS:

```
uname -m
```

x86_64: 64 bit kernel

i686: 32 bit kernel

Go to the [Oracle Java SE website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and decide which version you want to install:

**JDK:** Java Development Kit. Includes a complete JRE plus tools for developing, debugging, and monitoring Java applications.

**Server JRE:** Java Runtime Environment. For deploying Java applications on servers. Includes tools for JVM monitoring and tools commonly required for server applications.

Accept the license and copy the download link into your clipboard. Remember to choose the right tar.gz (64 or 32 bits). Use wget to download the archive into your server:

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Oracle does not allow downloads without accepting their license, therefore we needed to modify the header of our request. Alternatively, you can just download the compressed file using your browser and manually upload it using a SFTP/FTP client.

Always get the latest version from Oracle's website and modify the commands from this tutorial accordingly to your downloaded file.

**Installing Oracle JDK**

The /opt directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not part of the default installation. Create a directory for your JDK installation:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/jdk
```

and extract java into the "/opt/jdk" directory:

```
sudo tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk
```

Verify that the file has been extracted into the /opt/jdk directory.

```
ls /opt/jdk
```

**Setting Oracle JDK as the default JVM**

In our case, the java executable is located under /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java . To set it as the default JVM in your machine run:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100
```

and

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100
```

**Verify your installation**

Verify that java has been successfully configured by running:

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

and

```
update-alternatives --display javac
```

The output should look like this:

```
java - auto mode
link currently points to /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java
/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java - priority 100
Current 'best' version is '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java'.

javac - auto mode
link currently points to /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac
/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac - priority 100
Current 'best' version is '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac'.
```

Another easy way to check your installation is:

```
java -version
```

The output should look like this:

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

**(Optional) Updating Java**

To update Java, simply download an updated version from Oracle's website and extract it under the /opt/jdk directory, then set it up as the default JVM with a higher priority number (in this case 110):

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk.new.version/bin/java 110
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk.new.version/bin/javac 110
```

You can keep the old version or delete it:

```
update-alternatives --remove java /opt/jdk/jdk.old.version/bin/java
update-alternatives --remove javac /opt/jdk/jdk.old.version/bin/javac

rm -rf /opt/jdk/jdk.old.version
```

Comment: I should have added this, but in your case you will have to visit the Java site given in step one and re-download the correct version on a computer that has a working Internet connection.

Comment: I wonder if he got it...?

Comment: Using this mehtod, should I set `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` to `/opt/jdk/jdk.version/` ?