# Not able to install anything with sudo apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, java

I am having this error for a very long time and not able to figure out the solution. Whenever i am trying to install anything using

```
$ sudo apt-get install <package>
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u111+8u111arm-1~webupd8~0) ... Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2018-02-09 17:00:08--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 106.51.144.109 Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|106.51.144.109|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-02-09 17:00:08--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)...
104.122.10.148, 2600:140f:c000:189::2d3e, 2600:140f:c000:187::2d3e Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.122.10.148|:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1518175928_00ed0e25d1821b70eb9e792e6c25a9bf [following]
--2018-02-09 17:00:08--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1518175928_00ed0e25d1821b70eb9e792e6c25a9bf Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|106.51.144.109|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2018-02-09 17:00:08 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed. dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:  oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:   Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing:  oracle-java8-installer  oracle-java8-set-default
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried cleaning apt using

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

tried removing everything from `/var/cache regarding oracle-java8` but again whenever i tried the folder in `/var/cache/oracle-java8-installer` created.
i tried removing every lock file from `/var/cache and var/lib/dpkg`.

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

no matter whatever i try to install using `sudo apt-get`, this error comes up :(.

Answer (score 1):

This more looks like a Network failure.

If Everything sounds fine, you may try installing offline [Installing Java Offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712399/installing-java-offline)

Also Try

```
sudo apt-get purge
```

to clean configuration

```
sudo apt-get update
```

should list you any Packages built half the way.