# How to handle SWT applications in 16.04

Tags: java, gtk3, 16.04

It seems that SWT (eclipse based) applications in Xenial (16.04) are mostly broken with default-jdk (ie openjdk 8). This includes Eclipse IDE, Gantproject, etc...

They either won't load, or won't work as expected (never ending operations, ...). This is related to the fact that SWT integrates badly with GTK3, and especialy the latest version that ships with Xenial (look for SWT GTK3 in Google for tons of problems and blogs related to the issue).

Most of the time, `export SWT_GTK3=0` works around the issue (it falls back to GTK2).

So here is my question: what is the best way to handle this problem for Xenial ?

- set `SWT_GTK3=0` globally for the system (then how is it best done, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/environment`, ???) ?
- report the problem to Ubuntu to get it solved before the release ? Then, what are the relevant packages ? (default-jdk, swt-gtk, ???)
  Notice a bug report already exists on the subject: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swt-gtk/+bug/1552764, which I edited to make it more generic and not eclipse IDE only
- any other option ?

Comment: What JVM are you using? If you're unsure, what does `readlink -f /usr/bin/java` say?

Comment: Openjdk 8 (default-jdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has already been reported to Ubuntu at the link you provided, so nothing more needs to be done there just yet.

If `SWT_GTK3=0` works well, you should set it as unglobally as is feasible. There are a few ways to do it (choose the last one that will work for your situation):

- `/etc/environment` applies to everything for every user, not just Java programs
- `/etc/bash.bashrc` applies to things started from `bash` for every user, not just Java.
- `~/.bashrc` applies to things started from `bash` for the current user, not just Java.
- The following will apply to things started from `bash` for every user using the `java` command. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following:

```bash
    sudo -i
    mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
    echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/local/bin/java
    echo 'SWT_GTK3=0 /usr/bin/java $*' >> /usr/local/bin/java
    chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/java
    exit
    exit
```

- The following will apply to things started from `bash` for the current user using the `java` command. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following:

```bash
    mkdir -p ~/bin
    echo '#!/bin/sh' > ~/bin/java
    echo 'SWT_GTK3=0 /usr/bin/java $*' >> ~/bin/java
    chmod a+x ~/bin/java
    exit
```

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer. Excactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I just got `winbuilder designer` to work this morning.  I will share.

*Install oracle jdk8 and remove open jdk.* To purge  do this command.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
```

To install oracle jdk use the ppa and installer instructions.
The complex manual method and ppa method are found here.  (And google can help too if needed) 
[Replace openjdk with oracle-jdk on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430434/replace-openjdk-with-oracle-jdk-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Do you mean that SWT under Oracle JDK8 handles GTK3 better than OpenJDK8 ?

Comment: Yup!  try it.  I did the same thing.  It is a pisser because I want to install netbeans and I need open jdk for that.  I do not have much room for both oracle and open jdk.  also there is a setup issue for using either as default.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am quite reluctant to install / use non free software, and try to avoid it whenever possible. The SWT_GTK3=0 workaround fits me better than usning the non free Oracle JDK for now.

Comment: did it the other solution work?

Comment: Yes it did (I'm using the /etc/environment method)