# Ubuntu won't boot for my laptop

Tags: boot

I was trying to boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when it displayed this: "This kernel requires an x68-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU." What could I do to fix this?

Comment: the i686 is a 32bit CPU.  You downloaded the x86-64 which is a 64bit version and will not run on that CPU.

Comment: Could you give me a link pls?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/444394

Comment: @NovaBot please accept the heynnema answer

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the Ubuntu for 64-bit processor architecture. However, you need the one for 32-bit architecture. You can find it here http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-i386.iso