# Am I running 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, init

I know this question has been asked a number of times, but my system seems to contradict itself…

Following the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os) question, I have run the following:

```
$ uname -a
Linux manaha 3.13.7-x86_64-linode38 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 12:59:48 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xc0d86a25a7abb14cad4a65a1f7d03605bcbd41f6, stripped
```

So, while `uname` seems to suggest 64-bit, `/sbin/init` suggests 32-bit.  What's happening here?

Comment: That is strange! Did you ever re-compile the kernel yourself?

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` will give your original architecture.

Comment: `$ dpkg --print-architecture` yields `i386`.  I haven't recompiled the kernel -this box is hosted by Linode and recently I swapped to be kernel in their web management backend to enable some free upgrades they were offering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computing, the Executable and Linkable Format (ELF) is a common standard file format for executables, object code, shared libraries, and core dumps. In your question `/sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object` identifies ELF as the format for a 32-bit shared object from a shared library. Your operating system is a 64-bit OS that has a 32-bit shared object somewhere in it. There is no contradiction in this.

Comment: That would mean `file /sbin/init` is not a reliable method to know whether you are running a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS, right?

Comment: @Jobin `uname -a` is a simpler and less potentially confusing way to know whether you are running a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS than `file /sbin/init`.

Comment: So, if `init` is 32-bit, and `init` starts all processes (sorry, been a few years since I've done this low-level stuff), does this mean that I can only run 32-bit apps, but the kernel is running in 64-bit mode?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451875/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libogg-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-fil/451881#451881) that I posted today. It will also help to read the question and visit the link in the answer. In a nutshell, Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (64-bit Linux kernel) can also run 32-bit apps by running the command: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`.

Answer (score 0):

While the uname command tells you something about your system, the file command tells you something about a file. So the file command says "init" is a 32-bit file and the uname command says you have a 64-bit computer. I hope this helps.

**Please point out any mistakes I made as fast as possible**, just in case it causes any harm.

PS did you read the other answers to the post you're linking to? This answer seems a really easy way to find out your architecture: https://askubuntu.com/a/65731/271517