# Error while loading shared libraries: libogg.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 64-bit

I'm trying to install Auteria (32-bit) on my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (trusty). It used to work on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, but now when I try to start the game the terminal gives me the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: 
 libogg.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`locate libogg.so.0` gives me:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.1
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install libogg.so.0:386` but it tells me that no such package could be found.

Does anybody know if the 32-bit libogg.so.0 can be found in any package at all or is there another solution to this problem? Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

After that retry to install the Auteria game.

See also: [File list of package libogg0 in trusty of architecture i386](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libogg0/filelist) for the location of 32-bit libogg.so.0 in the filesystem.

Comment: That was not only very quick, it also worked! Thank you very much, karel!!!

Comment: Just did that. Would have upgraded, if I had enough reputation. Thanks again, karel.