# linux-3.14.4 kernel install problem in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, compiling

I am trying to install the latest kernel 3.14.4 on my Ubuntu 14.04. But it gives me an error when I try to install using make file. I have also done the `make oldconfig`, it took more than 3 hours to complete, and when I try to `make install`, a few errors are thrown in the terminal:

```
VirtualBox:/home/sonyx64/Documents/linux-3.14.4# make install

sh /home/sonyx64/Documents/linux-3.14.4/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.14.4 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.14.4 /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.14.4 /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.14.4
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.14.4
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.14.4: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_Xm5CtY/lib/modules/3.14.4/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_Xm5CtY/lib/modules/3.14.4/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.14.4 /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.14.4 /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.14.4 /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.15.0-1-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.15.0-1-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.14.4
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.4.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.14.4
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/05/how-to-install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-14-4-in-linux.html) (and [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kernel-3-14-4-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-their-derivative-systems/)), you should be able download the deb files from [`http://kernel.ubuntu.com`](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/) and install them.

To do this, run these commands in Terminal:

**To download for 32bit:**

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.4-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_all.deb

wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.4-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_i386.deb

wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.4-utopic/linux-image-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_i386.deb
```

**To download for 64bit**

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.4-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_all.deb

wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.4-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_amd64.deb

wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.4-utopic/linux-image-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_amd64.deb
```

<sup>To find your current kernel architecture (*bit), see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os)</sup>

**To install the downloaded deb files, run**

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.14.4-*.deb linux-image-3.14.4-*.deb
```

Then reboot.

**To uninstall, run**

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.14.4-* linux-image-3.14.4-*
```

You will need to reboot and choose it in Grub to use the kernel, you can find the kernel you are currently using by running:

```
uname -r
```

Comment: you mean we cannot use the kernel downloaded from kernel.org?????

Comment: you could probably use that, but this should work.

Comment: I have 32 bit lts, which one i should choose??

Comment: 32bit........... thats why i put in [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os) - if you run `uname -mpi` and get `i386`, `i586` or `i686` etc you need 32bit, where as if you end up with `x86_64` you need 64bit. I think you need to download and install all of the debs (`wget` will download the files) - if you a=only install 1 or 2 it will likely return the error that the 3rd needs to be installed.. You need to run the `commands` in terminal.

Comment: Can you give me the explanation of this command?? >`apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`

Comment: `apt-get` is the package manager, and `source` tells it download (and i think install) the source code of the given packages *(look for `source` in the output of `man apt-get` for a better explanation)*. The `$(uname -r)` gives the currently used *(and therefore already installed)* version of the kernel, and the `linux-image-` is start of the name of each kernel package. Basically it downloads and probably installs the source of the kernel currently in use.

Comment: I truly appreciate the time you spent to help me. Actually i am trying to make my own system call -> for that we need image of the kernel and i am in a confusion to download which one.

Comment: `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` will download the source of the current kernel - which would be what you need to create a syscall for the current kernel. (This seems a completely different question to this one, i would suggest making a new question for it). For making a basic system call, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rr_VoQCOgE) seems to give a great guide on how to do it.

Comment: yeah i followed this video and also blogs. Now i cleared my doubts, thank you.