# Should I install 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I was unsure so I had to ask. Sorry if this is duplicate. I don't know if the system I am running is 32 or 64 bit. It has 2GB of RAM, which is apparently an indicator that it is 64bit, and it is win8.1, which I've heard only comes in 64bit. However, DXDIAG tells me that I am running a 32 bit OS. I'd be happy to supply more info as you require, and thanks in advance.

Comment: `dxdiag`? which os you're currently running?

Comment: With only 2GB RAM i would use a 32bit System or do you plan to upgrade your RAM next time?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os

Comment: Are you currently running win8.1?

Comment: this may help you.. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what your system specifications are. If you are willing to install ubuntu, go with the 64 bit . It is always better. For yor ram though, 32 bit will work ok. Choose what you want, i would go with 64 bit.