# Interpreting uname output: 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: command-line, kernel, xubuntu, playonlinux

I used `uname` command and obtained:

```
Linux rufusruffcutt 3.2.0-35-generic-pae #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 18:04:39 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

What do this mean and how can I tell if this is a 32- or 64-bit kernel version?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I edited your question to make it a bit more clear --- at least I hope so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os)

Answer (score 5):

From `man uname`:

> -a, --all
>                 print  all  information,  in the following order, except omit -p
>                 and -i if unknown:
>
> ```
>    -s, --kernel-name
>           print the kernel name
>
>    -n, --nodename
>           print the network node hostname
>
>    -r, --kernel-release
>           print the kernel release
>
>    -v, --kernel-version
>           print the kernel version
>
>    -m, --machine
>           print the machine hardware name
>
>    -p, --processor
>           print the processor type or "unknown"
>
>    -i, --hardware-platform
>           print the hardware platform or "unknown"
>
>    -o, --operating-system
>           print the operating system
> ```

So in your case:

```
Linux       rufusruffcutt 3.2.0-35-generic-pae #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 18:04:39 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

So you have a machine hw which is  `i686`, a processor type `i686`, and a hw platform which is `i386`.

In Ubuntu builds, `i386` are the 32-bit builds; in a 64-bit system they would be `x86_64`.

Using `uname -i` should give you just the hardware platform.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use the `getconf` command:

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

It will shows you your kernel whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score -3):

i686 is the name of an Intel processor architecture with 32 bit word length.