# How to install JDownloader 2?

Tags: software-installation, jdownloader

There still isn't any post here in AskUbuntu about how to install the JDownloader 2 yet, so I decided to write this one. I googled a way to, and found one, but I sincerely think that there might be other ways, so I hope that you will share instructions for other ways to install it.

Comment: Btw, is the `add-apt-repository` better than installing from a silent installer script? I don't know the diferences.

Comment: Also, I can't create new tag `JDownloader2`. I'll let the community to decide wether or not to create the new tag; please change this question's tag if the new tag is created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, get the silent installer script for your system type.
For instructions on how to check your system type, [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os).
Open your terminal by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then type or copy&paste the following command:

- 32-bit OS:

```
wget http://installer.jdownloader.org/JD2SilentSetup_x86.sh
```

- 64-bit OS:

```
wget http://installer.jdownloader.org/JD2SilentSetup_x64.sh
```

Wait untill the download finishes, then give it executable permission and run it (don't forget to change `JD2SilentSetup*.sh` to the correct file name):

```
chmod +x JD2SilentSetup*.sh
./JD2SilentSetup*.sh
```

It'll bring up the install wizard. Follow the instructions and it will install automatically for you.
Thanks to [Ji M](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/about/) for posting instructions on [UbuntuHandBook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-jdownloader-2-beta-ubuntu-12-04-13-04/).
Thanks to @[MemPrices](https://askubuntu.com/users/426682/memprices) for letting us know that the necessary Java packages come built in the SH installer, so users don't have to install it beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

I woul like to tell you that actually any SH installer of JDownloader has its own Java Version, independent of the one you have installed into your system. So, basically, There's no need to pre-install Java before running the installer.

Nice day!

Comment: Hello, thank you for sharing this with us! I'll edit my answer, but can you also share any source? I can't look for it right now :(

Comment: Hi. I've confirmed it, it has a folder called `jre` in it and apparently has everything inside it. In case someone is concerned about it, I'll test if it works without preinstalling Java, when I have some more time to.

Comment: I've confirmed this and editted my answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One improvement though, as you pointed out in earlier posts, `jDownloader 2` has a `Java jre/ folder` bundled with it, which size is ~ 147 MB. This is not useful in any Ubuntu distribution. Debian / Ubuntu provides `java-7-openjdk` packages that will be shared by all applications using Java. You may have installed as well Oracle java 7 or 8 from packages build by [webupd8.org Install Oracle Java 8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html).

OpenJDK can be installed via Ubuntu's package system by running this command:

`$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk icedtea-7-plugin`

Function of each package:

`openjdk-7-jdk`     OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)

`icedtea-7-plugin`  web browser plugin based on OpenJDK and IcedTea to execute Java applets

These packages are installed in `/usr/lib/jvm` then you will see folder `java-7-openjdk` for OpenJDK and `java-7-oracle` or/and `java-8-oracle` for Java Oracle. Each of these install do have a `jre/` folder.

In addition the Java version used by default in your system should be defined (system wide for all users) in the file `/etc/profile` e.g. for `java-7-openjdk`

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_09
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_09
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

You may have to add or edit it, as the Ubuntu system uses `update-alternatives` to switch between installed versions of Java. These symbolic links are not per `jre/` folder but per executable file i.e. `java` `javac` ...

Then you have to edit the Bash launch script `jd2/JDownloader2` located in your home folder (`echo $HOME` in a Terminal), to add the following line as the first line of code below the comments ending `#INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS=`

`INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE="$JAVA_JRE"`

Or if you didn't define the jre/ folder

`INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE="$JAVA_HOME"/jre`

Afterwards you can remove the bundled `jd2/jre` folder. That would save you ~ 147 MB and have your Java JRE managed by the Ubuntu system.