# How do I replace some 32 bit packages with 64 bit ones?

Tags: apt, xubuntu, 64-bit

I installed some 32 bit packages on a 64 bit machine and it caused some problems.

- How do I replace all x86 packages with x64 ones?
- Can I at least check which packages are x86?

Comment: Can I at least check which packages are x86?

Comment: Retracted the close vote and comment; if it is about "some" packages purging and installing will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check packages installed with an architecture:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\t\t${Architecture}\n' | grep 'i386'
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\t\t${Architecture}\n' | grep 'amd64'
```

Use the line that is not your current architecture (in your case "i386") (and in case someone is unsure: you can check the architecture with `uname -a` (see [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os/41334#41334) ))

If it is not a lot of them you could purge them and install the other version.