# IPAD connectivity problem with ubuntu 14.04 hotspot

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

Tried to set up DHCP server on my Dell Inspiron desktop (Ubuntu 14.04 installed) but doesn't seem to work. So I'm trying to manually input static IP address, DNS info etc into the ipad directly, but it tells me that while I can connect to the network, the network is not connected to the internet. And my network only shows up under "devices" and not under "choose a network".
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
cheers

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu hotspot is not recognised by Android devices and probably not by the IPAD too. So, try installing ap-hotspot in Ubuntu. Open terminal and type the following,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

For 14.04, you need to uninstall the buggy hostapd

```
sudo apt-get remove hostapd
```

Then install the needed version - for 64 bit systems:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

and for 32 bit systems:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

Now ap-hotspot is installed.

To configure, type

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

Enter the appropriate interfaces, the hotspot name and password. 
To start the hotspot, type
    sudo ap-hotspot start

and to stop,

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Typed in "cd /tmp && wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb && sudo apt-mark hold hostapd" and got "404 not found". Also got a fail message earlier on; " * Starting DNS forwarder and DHCP server dnsmasq                               
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 10.42.0.1: Address already in use". Should I have removed the DHCP server first?

Comment: Did first three steps work? Then, try sudo ap-hotspot configure

Comment: The first 3 steps worked.  The step for 64 bit systems returned a 404 not found error. And when I tried to configure ap-hotspot I got "sudo: ap-hotspot: command not found"

Comment: did sudo apt-get remove hostapd work? and yes, try removing the previously created DHCP server

Comment: It seems I was able to remove the DHCP server. Then I did your first 3 steps again (no problems) and removed the hostapd. But the next step for 64 bit systems ends with a 404 not found. Here is the terminal:

Comment: mike@mike-Inspiron-545:~$ cd /tmp && wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb && sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
--2015-06-23 22:12:55--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.14, 91.189.91.15, 91.189.91.24, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-06-23 22:12:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: mike@mike-Inspiron-545:/tmp$ sudo ap-hotspot configure
sudo: ap-hotspot: command not found

Comment: @kokuraMike You have said you have removed hostapd, then try the following steps one by one:

Comment: cd /tmp, then wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb, after that,  sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb, finally  sudo apt-mark hold hostapd

Comment: The above can work because we are downloading from old-releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: @spharish I just encountered the 404 issue trying to set up ap-hotspot, and forgot old stuff gets move to the old-releases server - thanks! N.B. using the old version of hostapd that ap-hotspot needs may be a massive security risk....

Comment: I really appreciate all your help, but I'm still getting a 404 not found error. Is the fact I live in Japan a problem somehow?

Comment: The answer is edited now, do you mean you are getting the same error now also, after doing everything from first? @kokuraMike

Comment: Yes. So I went to the  "old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/…" site in my web browser and installed the software from there, but the terminal says "dpkg: error processing archive hostapd*.deb, (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hostapd*.deb" when I type in " sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb".

Comment: @Wilf do you have any solution for the above problem?

Comment: Try using the command (not a browser) to download the package from the old-releases URL (I updated the commands in the answer), but specify the package name - e.g. for 64bit: `wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb`. If you need help working out whether you have 32bit or 64bit, use http://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os . You may need to reinstall ap-hotspot if you used `sudo apt-get remove hostapd`.