# Wrong system architecture detected

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, cpu-architecture

I have recently reinstalled my Ubuntu 14.04 (after introducing some changes to the disk) and I have run into a strange problem. I have 64 bit processor and I've installed 64 bit system [(as shown in picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP0Ou.png) and when I run `uname -m` I have [this response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvDEF.png) telling me it's 32 bit. Does anyone have idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: what's the outputs of the other commands? [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](http://askubuntu.com/q/41332/253474)

Comment: Well, I've reainstalled sytem yet, but thanks for your willingness to help :)