# Do you know how to install google chrome to my desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, downloads

Can you help me download Google Chrome to my desktop, My OS is Ubuntu Linux, Or is Google no longer supporting it for 32-bit? What comes up after I click install is 64-bit, Will that work, Or is Google no longer supporting 32-bit? Also, Which one do I need 34-bit, Or 64-bit to install it? Can you please help Me?

Leah (Ubuntu Linux user for over a decade)!

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit OS or a 64-bit OS? ([How to check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os))

Comment: Google Chrome does not support 32 bit any more.

Comment: Please run _uname -m_ to see if your Ubuntu is 32-bit ("i686" or "i386") or 64-bit ("x86_64"). If you see "x86_64" you have 64-bit Ubuntu and can run 64-bit apps. If you don't see "x86_64", then run _lscpu | grep "op-mode"_ ; if the result  shows "32-bit, 64-bit" you can step up to 64-bit Ubuntu and 64-bit apps. If it only shows "32-bit" you are limited to 32-bit OS and apps only.

Comment: if your system is not too old, supports 64-bit OS then only my suggestion is to install 64-bit version OS. Otherwise, you ran out of luck. I found this article having a little bit of more information and alternative. You can take a look [Google Is Ending Chrome support for 32-bit Linux, Ubuntu 12.04 And Debian 7](https://itsfoss.com/google-ending-chrome-32-bit/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you bought your computer >10 years ago, you probably need the 64 bit install.

To install Chrome on Ubuntu, try the following in a terminal:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Once that is done, install it with:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

else, you could instead install Chromium, it's open-source and is less invasive:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest distro of Chrome is not available for 32bit applications.
Unless your hardware is limited to 32bit re-install a 64bit version of 18.04 and you can install the latest version of Chrome either from https://google.com/chrome or following the command line above.