# How to get system architecture

Tags: system

While i was initializing a software i required to put my system architecture in a command which is mentioned in the picture[image]. Please suggest how to check my systems architecture in a format given in example of initialization section mentioned in the picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os) Run `uname -m` or `arch` in a terminal window.

Comment: The commands env and set will list all the environment variables in your system so you can check that against your picture. More on this here;  https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/